# Reactjs need to combine the const in Render with axios call in componentDidMount to create DOM element table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, axios

Problem:  I was able to do a web api call with axios in componentDidMount, then in Render I could loop over the data with .map and create the html with table and bootstrap classes.   Issue I am having is that requirement is that I need to have buttons that show whether they are members in local storage or not. 
Thus now i think that I need to move all out of Render() and put the loop and if/else checks to display the correct button inside the webapi .then section

What is the best way to do this with html tables and data in axios call?

componentDidMount With Axios web api call:

```
 componentDidMount() {

    webApi.get('sai/getofflinemembers?userId=N634806')
        .then((event) => {

          // Instead of looping with .map in the render(), thinking I need to
          // do the looping inside here to correctly create the correct element 
          // with the right color button and text 
          for (var i = 0; i < event.data.length; i++) {

             //check with local storage if the memberid exist
             // need to use a different button style and text
             if (localStorage.getItem(event.data[i]["Member_ID"]) != null) {
                //document.getElementById(event.data[i]["Member_ID"]).classList.remove('btn-warning');
                //above would be after 
                // need to DO ALL in render  const contents html table in here 
                // <button id={item.Member_ID} type="button" onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID,e)} 
                  className="btn btn-success">SAI</button>
             }

          }

          this.setState({
                data: event.data
          });


    });
```

Render:

```
 render() {

    const contents = this.state.data.map(item => (
         <tr>
              <td>{item.Member_Name}</td> 
              <td>{item.Member_ID}</td>
              <td>{item.Member_DOB}</td>
              <td>{item.ProgramType}</td>
              <td>
                <button id={item.Member_ID} type="button" onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID,e)} 
                  className="btn btn-warning">Ready for Download</button>
              </td>
         </tr>
        ))
        return(
         ....
         {contents}
         ....
        )
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I've updated my answer below. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lifecycle-methods like `componentDidMount` and `render` have a standard segregation of roles. Typically, the former is meant to do some API call (like what you have), and the latter, render is used to generate the markup. You should avoid trying to generate markup in `componentDidMount` not like it's really possibly anyway.

It sounds like all you're trying to do is check whether an item returned from the API is available in the localStorage, then conditionally change the `className` for that button depending on its existence. You can just create a helper function to help you accomplish that.

```
checkItem = (item) => {
    let className;
    if(localStorage.getItem(item["Member_ID"]) != null){
       className = "btn btn-success"
    } else {
       className = "btn btn-warning"
    }
    return className
}
```

Then since you're mapping over the array of items, we can just call this function in-line with your mark-up.

```
 render() {

    const contents = this.state.data.map(item => (
         <tr>
              <td>{item.Member_Name}</td> 
              <td>{item.Member_ID}</td>
              <td>{item.Member_DOB}</td>
              <td>{item.ProgramType}</td>
              <td>
                <button id={item.Member_ID} type="button" onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID,e)} 
                  className={this.checkItem(item)}>Ready for Download</button>
              </td>
         </tr>
        ))
        return(
         ....
         {contents}
         ....
        )
    }
```

Comment: 1. I put a console.log inside checkItem... It is not getting called.  2.  do I need to set/create checkItem in constructor or state etc.. ?    I tried const and var in front and that doesn't work (error)

Comment: Oh my bad. It's just className={this.checkItem(item)}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount{
    webApi.get('sai/getofflinemembers?userId=N634806')
    .then(event => {
         this.setState({
              data: event.data
         });
    })
}

const isExistLocalStorage = value => {
    return localStorage.getItem(value) ? true : false;
}
render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
        data && data.map((item, index) => {
            const isExist = isExistLocalStorage(item.Member_ID);
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{item.Member_Name}</td>
                <td>{item.Member_ID}</td>
                <td>{item.Member_DOB}</td>
                <td>{item.ProgramType}</td>
                <td>
                    <button
                        id={item.Member_ID}
                        type="button"
                        onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID, e)}
                        className={`btn ${isExist ? "btn-success" : "btn-warning"}`}
                    > {isExist ? "Ready for Download" : "Not ready"}</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: It doesn't like const isExistLocalStorage outside of the render()  not sure how to fix that

Comment: I created a new question, If you have a second to take a look   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174810/reactjs-need-to-conditionally-display-different-onclick-vs-link-based-on-logic