# ReactJS need to conditionally display different onclick vs Link based on logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, object-literal

Goal I have it to display different HTML with onclick vs.  route

Without logic in the Render()   `const contents = this.state.data.map(item => (`

**This is the logic I'm struggling with**

```
<button id={item.Member_ID} type="button"
  {` ${this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? <Link to='surveysai/'>
      <button type="button" className='btn btn-success'>SAI</button>  </Link>             
    : ${onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID, e)}}`}
    className={`btn ${this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? "btn-success" : "btn-warning"}`} > {this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? "SAI" : "Ready for Download"}</button>
```

**This WORKS from button class:**

```
<button id={item.Member_ID} type="button"
 className={`btn ${this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? "btn-success" : "btn-warning"}`} > {this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? "SAI" : "Ready for Download"}</button>
```

**Below is OLD code BEFORE changing to conditional , below is not code i want , for reference only.**

**onclick**

```
<button id={item.Member_ID} type="button" onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID,e)} 
      className={() => this.checkItem(item.Member_ID)}>Ready for Download</button>
```

**Link route redirect**

```
<Link to='surveysai/'>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-success">SAI</button>                   
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you conditionally render either the `Link` or the button.

```
{this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? (
  <Link to='surveysai/'>
      <button type="button" className='btn btn-success'>SAI</button>  
  </Link>
) : (
  <button 
    onClick={(e) => this.downloadUser(item.Member_ID, e)}
    className={`btn ${this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? "btn-success" : "btn-warning"}`}> {this.isExist(item.Member_ID) ? "SAI" : "Ready for Download"} . 
  </button>
)}
```

Also, you don't actually need to render a button inside of a `Link`, assuming this is a React Router `Link` component. You can just pass classnames as props like:

`<Link to="/wherever" className="btn btn-success" />`